# How to log original value of $remote_addr when using Real-IP

Tags: nginx, logging, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

My environment has user requests passing through a number of systems:

[Client] --> [ELB] ---> [nginx] --> [web]

(ELB = AWS Elastic Load Balancer)

Thanks to this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/414166/72096), I have nginx determining and passing the correct client IP address to the upstream servers (web) with the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Real_IP` headers. The relevant nginx config:

```
    real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from        10.0.0.0/8;
    real_ip_recursive   on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

My problem is this, the Real IP module in nginx **replaces** the existing `$remote_addr` variable with the result of its `X-Forwarded-For` calculations. This gives me the originating client IP, but I'm losing the IP address of the system that actually sent the request to the proxy (i.e. the ELB).

Overall, having the client IP is more important to me, but I would like to be able to log the full chain of requests so I can understand (and debug) how traffic is flowing. Currently, I can only have nginx log the client IP, its own IP, and the upstream server IP. I would like to be able to log the ELB IP as well.

I see [X-Istence](https://serverfault.com/users/2042/x-istence) asked the same [question](https://serverfault.com/q/486334/72096) in 2013, with little luck. Has anything changed or improved since then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the original client address of the connecting ELB in [the variable `$realip_remote_addr`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#variables), but be aware that this variable was only added in nginx 1.9.7, so you'll need to be running a very recent version of nginx.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hampton♦! I was coming back to answer my own question because after pursuing an alternate strategy, I finally stumbled upon `$realip_remote_addr`. It works beautifully. Was actually trying to get proxy_protocol to work and came upon the nginx patch notes for 1.9.7